# memory allocation for mapping variables in solidity

Tags: mapping, solidity

After reading "100" posts about it, I have the same doubt.

A mapping variable use keccak256(key.slot) as index, which means 2^256 indexes to 32 bytes words.

(2^256)*32 bytes doesn't sound to me like a rasonable number.

- Too much space wasted.
- Smart contracts must have a limited storage capacity but (2^256)*32 bytes is no that "limited".

Could anyone put some light on this... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of slots is correct - but it doesn't mean that there is (2^256)*32 bytes of storage allocated on every node.

Each full node currently (2023) holds approx. 1TB of current state data ([source](https://etherscan.io/chartsync/chaindefault)) that consists not only from contract storage slots but also contract bytecode and other data (e.g. few latest blocks). If you want to hold also all previous states, that's roughly 14TB ([source](https://etherscan.io/chartsync/chainarchive)).

How a node maps the storage slot number to an actual file storage, depends on each specific node client software. For example Go Ethereum [uses](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/fundamentals/databases) LevelDB key/value database.

- The key is the combination of contract address and its storage slot number.
- And the value is the actual non-zero value.
- If the value is zeroed-out, then the whole record is removed from the database to not take up too much space.

Comment: In an array you have something like this: a[0]=10, a[1]=33, a[2]=54, this is ultra fast if you look for the value of index=2 because you don't need iterate, but you cann't have empty indexes (i.e: a[1] must have its memory space even if it is empty). I thought mappings were something like this as far as you cannot iterate through them but only access a known key (i.e: a[2]). As far as key are 32 bytes hashes, you would need (2^255)-1 slots that could be empty but should be reserved (not used to avoid overwriting data). Sorry, I think I miss something.

Comment: @J.PabloGarcía These slots are **not reserved**, so statistically it's possible for the data to be overridden because of a hash collision. But the probability is very very close to 0, and there has been **no hash collision** found in the kecaak256 hashing algorithm yet, and likely will not be found with our current technology.

Comment: 1TB = 1^40 bytes = 2^35 words (32 bytes/word). We are talking about 2^221 times 1TB in memory space... is this even possible?. I think these numbers are astronomical. Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: @J.PabloGarcía No worries. The important factor is that the empty values are not stored and not reserved anywhere. That's why the actual amount of data stored is so relatively small... Take the following mapping for example: `[0 => "abc", 1 => "def", ... 1000 => "ghi", ... 5000 => "jkl"]` Even though the highest key is 5000, it only contains 4 values - all others are empty. So the only thing that is stored on the actual harddrive is the 4 keys and 4 values - the empty values in between are not reserved, and not stored.

Comment: I am agree, this is only possible if empty addresses are not saved. So, if you have this: [0 => "abc", 1 => "def", ... 1000 => "ghi", ... 5000 => "jkl"], "ghi" is NOT in memory address 1000, ¿how can you read directly "ghi" based on its key (1000) without knowing the memory address of "ghi"?, there must be some direct relation between they key (1000) and the memory address of "ghi" (let's say for example 157). ¿1000 => &157? therefore the rest of the aray (for 1 byte word): 0=>&155, 1=>&156, 1000=>&157, 5000=>&158. ¿which one is it?

Comment: @J.PabloGarcía The mapping values are stored in persistent **storage** - not in temporary **memory**... There's a universal way (between all EVM clients) to calculate the storage slot ID from **hash** of the position of the state variable and the index. See https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/internals/layout_in_storage.html#mappings-and-dynamic-arrays for more detailed calculation... But each EVM client uses a different way to map the storage slot ID to an actual file on a disk and to a specific part of the file. So that depends on each specific implementation of the client software.

Comment: Thank you, that document reference was great!

Answer (score 0):

keys in mapping are not stored anywhere. key gets hashed, that result gives the memory address and you store the value inside that memory address.

Solidity storage is like a bytes array

```
[[slot1],[slot2],.....]
```

you have (2^256)-1 slots and each slots has 32 bytes. this whole data structure is not stored in clients. clients only store the slots that have value

Comment: I know that hashes are not saved. For values, if you only save not null values of couse it is more viable but, if that were the case, how do you handle no used slots?. I mean, you could need any slot between 0 and (2^256)-1 at any time, so you can not use that memory for other porpouses because you could overwrite data. What do I miss?